# Error with conversion codes from object to image

Tags: c#, image, winforms, background

Hi everyone i am trying to convert an object that is taken from the database and store to change it to the background of the application

```
 con.Open();
        string sqlSelectQuery = "Select * FROM Backgrounds where UserID = '" + 1 + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {


               byte[] yourImage = (byte[])(dr["Background"]);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(yourImage);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                this.BackgroundImage = image;
            }
con.Close();
```

[Error that is shown during the conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRfJf.png)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Backgrounds] (
    [UserID]     INT   DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Background] IMAGE NULL,
    [Logo1]      IMAGE NULL,
    [Logo2]      IMAGE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
```

What i want is the object that is taken from the database to be retrieved and use as the current background.Please let me know any mistakes that was made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I downvoted your question for [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: I am screenshotting the error?

Comment: In that case, please provide an [mcve]

Comment: dont understand... didn't i filtered out the necessary codes that would cause the error?

Comment: I don't see any code. Where is your code? You have already said that the purpose of the image is not to show your code. I'm not about to manually type in all of your code just to test your question. No way.

Comment: done added code but you will not be able to test this unless you use the same database details

Comment: Can you add the table definition?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175209/retrieve-images-from-sql-server-database) help?

Comment: still get the same problem

Comment: _"you will not be able to test this unless you use the same database"_ -- which is a strong signal you should observe telling you that you haven't provided a suitable [mcve]. In any case, the `ArgumentException` you're seeing is thrown for any variety of reasons, all involving the bitmap data being invalid or unsupported.

Comment: i dont really understand what the code means for the duplicate link that was given... Is there any way you can explain it if not it is quite hard for me to visualize and put it into my project...

Comment: _"it is quite hard for me to visualize and put it into my project"_ -- the point is that you first need to identify what it is about the data that is preventing it from working. There are many different reasons a stream purporting to be a bitmap would not be decoded successfully. One option is to just catch the exception and ignore such images. But if you want to _fix_ the problem, you need to do some more diagnosis yourself, based on the information in the marked duplicate. You haven't provided enough context here for anyone else to help.