# How to retrieve image from database of image datatype to the PhotoBox in c#

Tags: c#, database, forms, image

The code below is my photo selecting selector (the other button I have in my project is just sending the `picArray` to the table in the column of image `datatype`):

```
private void FileSelectorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog ImageSelectorWindow = new OpenFileDialog();
        ImageSelectorWindow.Filter = "JPG |*.jpg|PNG |*.png|Bitmap |*.bmp";
        ImageSelectorWindow.Title = "Choose an Image";
        if (ImageSelectorWindow.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = ImageSelectorWindow.FileName;


            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            picArray = new byte[fs.Length];

            fs.Read(picArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();
        }

        TBFilePath.Text = fileName;

    }
```

Below is my image retrieval code:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT avatar FROM Members WHERE Id = '" + value + "'", con);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dr[0]);

PBMemberImage.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
```

This is giving me the following exception:

[image]

Can someone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

[Retrieve Images from sql server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175209/retrieve-images-from-sql-server-database)

Take a look at that and try the code below for retrieving your image. Let me know if that works or not.

```
byte[] img = (byte[])cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
PBMemberImage.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
```

Comment: **Its giving this exception now after your code** @forwardi
System.ArgumentException: Parameter not Valid

Comment: Which line specifically is it saying that's on?

Comment: PBMemberImage.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms); //On this line